# How to change the Print output of a Pythin dict to Json

Tags: python, json

Hi i'm coming from C# programming and am new to python so i don't really know the Syntax all that well so please forgive me if i did some very stupid rookie mistakes.

the code i have written so far:

```
def main(name):
filename = "hostname_list.yaml"
hostname_list = { }

with open(filename) as infile:
    hostname_list = yaml.safe_load(infile)
    json.dumps(infile)
    hostname_list = [s for s in hostname_list['sap_landscape'][name].items()]

    print(hostname_list)
```

it loads a YAML File into a dictionary and then loops over it to find a certain key in the dictionary and then print this key with it's values.

i get the following output (example output, slightly changed so no data gets compromised):

```
[('hostname', 'server3443'), ('SDI', 'T'), ('Type', 'Spo'), ('Land', 'DDD'), ('Severity', 'FTS'), ('Username', None), ('UserID', None), ('Global', None), ('Cycle', 2)]
```

i need this output now in a JSON Format like this:

```
{"hostname": "server3443", "SDI": "T", "Type": "Spo", "Land": "DDD", "Severity": "FTS", "Username": None, "UserID": None, "Global": null, "Cycle": 1}
```

how can i achieve this output? i have been trying to find a solution since about 1,5 weeks now and nothing i tried worked so far and i am quite literally clueless what to do.. .

Thanks in advance
Fex

Comment: Have you tried with `print(json.dumps(hostname_list))` ?

Comment: What does `print(hostname_list['sap_landscape'][name])` do?

Comment: @JoseKilo Yes i have, that just gives the following output:
[["hostname", "dceu1501"], ["SID", "TST"], ["Type", "Spool"], ["Landscape", "SBX"], ["Severity", "SBX"], ["Username", null], ["UserID", null], ["Global", null], ["Cycle", 2]]

which sadly still isn't correct

Comment: @Greedo it just give me the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with those libraries but

```
hostname_list = [s for s in hostname_list['sap_landscape'][name].items()]
```

... is a list comprehension which creates a list object. Try a dictionary comprehension instead:

```
hostname_list = {key:value for key, value in hostname_list['sap_landscape'][name].items()}
```